# How do I archive and retrieve a large HTML dataset?

Tags: war, common-crawl, warc, bigdata

I am a fresher and I am about to participate in a contest this weekend. The problem is about archiving and retrieving a large HTML dataset and I have no idea about it. My friend suggested to me to use a web archive and common crawl. Please suggest to me a way to convert the HTML dataset into a web archive and how to index them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [WARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_ARChive) format is a widely used standard, definitely a good decisions to archive web pages. Also the HTTP headers are contained in the WARC file. As a consequence, you need a crawler to create a WARC file. If the HTML pages are provided as a collection of files, you would need to crawl the file system (ev. via a local HTTP server) to get the content into a WARC file.

Everything else depends on the concrete task: there are many tools and libraries

1. to crawl and export the content as WARC: the simplest is `wget --warc-file` but there are many more
2. to read WARC files and process the content.

See [The WARC Ecosystem](http://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=The_WARC_Ecosystem) for a collection of tools. If you just need a serious WARC file to start with, fetch one from Common Crawl, e.g., https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-30/segments/1469257824853.47/warc/CC-MAIN-20160723071024-00101-ip-10-185-27-174.ec2.internal.warc.gz

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Heritrix` Crawler to crawl the websites you require. This can be automated via `CURL` requests simply writing a `Shell` Script.

Once you have crawled the websites, you can install `OpenWayBack`, to 'play back' archived websites in your browser.

The `OpenWayback` comes with a tool: `CDX-Indexer` which could be used for `indexing` the crawled Websites.

The current `OpenWayBack` is not under development and you may use `WaybackPY` for the playing of the WARCs.